# textarea max-width when is set COLS

Tags: html, css, textarea

it looks that textarea don't respect the css max-width when is setted to 100% and it is ok when setted to fixed pixels

```
<textarea cols="80">text here</textarea>
```

and

```
max-width: 100%;
```

or

```
max-width: 100px;
```

See the snippet code for max-width: 100%:

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  display:table;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #DAC082;
}

textarea {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <p>textarea cell</p>
    <textarea cols="80">TEXT</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

and see the snippet code for max-width: 100px:

```css
.table {
  width: 100%;
  display:table;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #DAC082;
}

textarea {
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <p>textarea cell</p>
    <textarea cols="80">TEXT</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that in the first example the textarea is overriding the css max-width 100%, I suppose it is wrong and It should be into 300px of table-cell width.
In the second example textarea stay into 100px: It works.

N.B. my browser is Firefox ESR 60.3. Is a firefox bug?

Comment: Shouldn't the outermost div have `display:table`?

Comment: Yes, it has display:table, I have edited the bug but the problem remains.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
textarea {
    width: 100%;
}
```

this worked for me and matched the width of whatever I set in .table-cell

Answer (score 0):

Table cells have a tendency to treat their `width` properties as hints rather than being set in stone.

One solution is to put an extra div in the table cell around the content, and set the width of that one. Then the textarea will honour it.

```css
.table {
    width: 100%;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #DAC082;
}

.table-cell>div {
  width: 300px;
}

textarea {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <div>
      <p>textarea cell</p>
      <textarea cols="80">TEXT</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Update: after it has become more clear what you want, a new solution is as follows: don't assign width properties to the table, but assign them to the content instead; then the table will mold itself to its contents rather than vice versa.

```css
.table {
  display: table;
}

.table-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #DAC082;
}

textarea {
  max-width: calc(100vw - 16px - 20px); /* = viewport - body margin - cell padding */
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">
    <p>textarea cell</p>
    <textarea cols="80">TEXT</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```

The max-width of the textarea is the width of the viewport, minus the margin of the body and the padding in the cell. You can adjust this to your needs of course!

Comment: It looks a good solution, an extra div is simple to add. By the way it is a bug. I use .table-cell div{} I suppose is the same.

Comment: Edit: It is not the final workaround because if  .table-cell>div {
  width: 100%;
} the workaround don't works. See this code: http://jsfiddle.net/zt1rq6v9/1/

Comment: @kensan In the fiddle, you don't have any fixed width. The table treats its width as (more or less) min-width, so the inner div gets "100% of at least the viewport width". So what do you want to achieve? A table that is always 100% wide? Then don't give widths to the table and the cells, but make sure the _contents_ are that wide. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/zt1rq6v9/2/ This makes the structure easier as well. But you didn't make that clear in the question. Anyway, I updated my answer now; better?

Comment: Yes I was not clear in my question because I supposed that max-width applied to textarea was easy to do without trouble or bug. Now I should be explain exactly what I want to do. I have two textarea with cols="nn" (nn big for desktop resolution) and I want fit it into a viewport size for smartphone. The two textarea is inside two frame, padding and margin of many size. I can calculate the size of space around the textarea1 and around the textarea2 and apply two different max-width: calc(). So I can use your workaround. TY.